# Discord Collector Unable To Collect DMs

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I am unable to collect a DM in discord.js when i try to use discord message collector

i have tried changing "message.channel" to message.author but it won't work

```js
const collector = new discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, { time: 30000 });
        collector.on('collect', message => {
            if (message.content == strng) {
                message.channel.send(`Successfully Verified User: <@${message.author.id}>`).then(m => {
                    m.delete(30000)
                    message.member.addRole('470615991555063808')
                }).catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
        })
```

expected: user DMs bot with correct string and it verifies them

actual: user has to put the string in the same channel as the user originally said !verify

Comment: Can you share any Errors which you may have received? Additionally, your `message.member.addRole()` won't work in DMs

Comment: the bot is a verify bot... you say ``!verify`` in the server and if you do the verification correctly, it gives you the role

Comment: also, no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user has to put the string in the same channel because you're collecting messages in said channel with `message.channel` as the first MessageCollector argument.
Instead, what you could do is open a DMChannel with the user and return it with `.then()` like so:

```
 message.author.createDM().then(dmchannel => {
 const collector = new discord.MessageCollector(dmchannel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, { time: 30000 });
   collector.on('collect', m => {
     if (m.content == strng) {
       message.channel.send(`Successfully Verified User: <@${message.author.id}>`)
      .then(m => {
         m.delete(30000)
          message.member.addRole('470615991555063808')}).catch(err => console.log(err))}
         })
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

i have worked it out...

i used

```js
message.author.createDM().then(c => {
            var verified = new discord.RichEmbed()
                .setTitle("Verification Started")
                .addField("**User**", `${message.author}`, false)
                .setFooter("Goriko Bot")
                .setColor(0xfffb00)
                .setTimestamp();
            message.guild.channels.get('470619175547830315').send(verified).catch(err => console.log(err));
            console.log("DM Created")
            c.send(verifyEmbed)
            console.log(`Embed Sent to ${message.author.tag}`)
            const filter = m => m.content.includes("~");
            const collector = c.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 30000 })
            console.log("Collector Created")
            collector.on('collect', m => {
                console.log('Reply Collected')
                if (m.content === strng) {
                    console.log('Success')
                    c.send("Successfully Verified")
                    if (message.channel.type == "dm") return;
                    message.member.addRole('470615991555063808').catch(err => console.log(err));
                    var successEmbed = new discord.RichEmbed()
                        .setTitle("Verification Successful")
                        .addField("**User**", `${message.author}`, true)
                        .addField("**String**", `\`\`${strng}\`\``, true)
                        .setFooter("Goriko Bot")
                        .setColor(0x00ff00)
                        .setTimestamp();
                    message.guild.channels.get('470619175547830315').send(successEmbed).catch(err => console.log(err));
                } else {
                    var failEmbed = new discord.RichEmbed()
                        .setTitle("Verification Failed")
                        .addField("**User:**", `${message.author}`, true)
                        .addField("**Correct Token:**", `${strng}`, true)
                        .addField("**Token Given:**", `${m.content}`, true)
                        .setColor(0xff0000)
                        .setFooter("Goriko Bot")
                        .setTimestamp();

                    message.guild.channels.get('470619175547830315').send(failEmbed).catch(err => console.log(err));
                    m.reply("Invalid Token! Please Try Again")
                }
            })
        })
```